# How to use the result of a SELECT in Table A, to limit the SELECT of Table B using IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to use the result of a SELECT inside of the IN operator of another SELECT but it takes 15 minutes, but if I run the queries(Query1 and Query 2 below) separate I have results in 2 minutes approximate

I tried to use the result of a SELECT inside of the IN clause of another SELECT but it's really slow

```
        Query 1  takes 1 minute
        SELECT Id_A 
        FROM [Database]..[Table_A] 
        WHERE location = 'US'
        AND datetime_in >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
        AND (
        CASE WHEN date_sent IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(hh, datetime_in, GETDATE())
        WHEN date_sent IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(hh, datetime_in, ship_date)
        ELSE 0 END) > 120

        Query 2  takes 10 seconds
        SELECT *
        FROM [Database]..[Table_B]
        WHERE Id_B IN (HERE I INSERT MANUALLY ALL THE Table_A..Id_A)

        Query 3 taking more then 15 minutes this is the one giving me issues
        SELECT *
        FROM [Database]..[Table_B]
        WHERE Id_B IN (SELECT Id_A 
        FROM [Database]..[Table_A] 
        WHERE location = 'US'
        AND datetime_in >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
        AND (CASE WHEN date_sent IS NULL 
        THEN DATEDIFF(hh, datetime_in, GETDATE())
        WHEN date_sent IS NOT NULL 
        THEN DATEDIFF(hh, datetime_in, ship_date)
        ELSE 0 END) > 120)
```

I am trying to optimize so the query 3 can be executed and give results in less then 5 minutes maybe?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic you want to implement.  (3) Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff is this question more understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much data you're working with, utilising temporary tables and indices on those tables may be the most optimal approach. It's a technique I tend to use regularly when I work with databases with insufficient indices, or where correlated subqueries are expensive:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ids;
SELECT Id_A
INTO #ids
FROM [Database]..[Table_A] 
WHERE location = 'US'
AND datetime_in >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
AND (
    CASE WHEN date_sent IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(hh, datetime_in, GETDATE())
    WHEN date_sent IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(hh, datetime_in, ship_date)
    ELSE 0 END
) > 120;
CREATE INDEX [IX_ids] ON #ids(Id_A);

SELECT *
FROM [Database]..[Table_B]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM #ids WHERE Id_A = Id_B
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are just trying to do a JOIN. Why not trying to make it simple, it will be MUCH faster that way:

```
    SELECT TB.*
    FROM [Database]..[Table_B] AS TB
    JOIN [Database]..[Table_A] AS TA
        ON TB.Id_B = TA.Id_A
    WHERE TA.location = 'US'
        AND TA.datetime_in >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
        AND (CASE WHEN TA.date_sent IS     NULL THEN DATEDIFF(hh, TA.datetime_in, GETDATE())
                  WHEN TA.date_sent IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(hh, TA.datetime_in, TA.ship_date)
    ELSE 0 END) > 120)
```

Comment: When I do the JOIN as you recommend , the query takes up to 15 minutes to bring the results, If I use the temporary table it takes 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Looks weird to me, how may records do you have in each table. Are the to columns Id_A and Id_B, clustered index, and indexed in the same direction (ASC or DESC)?    What are the type of Id_A and Id_B? Is TA.datetime_in indexed too? Thanks for replying, I'm curious...